# Is it possible to dynamically assign an array of structs in C?

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment, dynamic-variables

In a project I'm working on, I find myself creating a lot of small, hand-written arrays of structs that need to be stored in dynamically allocated memory (mostly for testing with small datasets before importing from a file). There's a really nice syntax to initialize a static array of structs, as `vec2` below, but I've been using the solution `vec3` below that uses `memcpy`.

`vec4` shows sort of what I'd like to be able to do, but obviously it doesn't quite work. Even though the anonymous array `*((struct vec2d[]) { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} })` contains three `strut vec2d`s, when it (and the LHS) are dereferenced, they become `(struct vec2d)`, so only the first `struct vec2d` gets assigned to the memory allocated at `vec4`.

Is there some way for me to accomplish this purely as an assignment, without using memcpy?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct vec2d
{
  double x,y;
};

//void print_vec2d(char *, struct vec2d *);

void print_vec2ds(char *label, size_t count, struct vec2d *vec)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    printf("%s (%li of %li): (%f, %f)\n", label, i + 1, count, (vec[i]).x, (vec[i]).y);
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int 
main(int c, char **a)
{
  // nice and concise syntax
  struct vec2d vec2[3] =
  {
    {12, 34},
    {56, 78},
    {90, 112}
  };
  print_vec2ds("vec2", 3,  vec2);

  // a little bulky to have to wrap it all in a call to memcpy
  struct vec2d *vec3 = calloc(3, sizeof(struct vec2d));
  memcpy(vec3, (struct vec2d[])
  {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
  }, 3*sizeof(struct vec2d));
  print_vec2ds("vec3", 3,  vec3);

  // this doesn't (and shouldn't) work, but I like the syntax :)
  struct vec2d *vec4 = calloc(3, sizeof(struct vec2d));
  *vec4 = *((struct vec2d[])
  {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
  });
  print_vec2ds("vec4", 3,  vec4);
}
```

program output, showing how last assignment doesn't work:

```
vec2 (1 of 3): (12.000000, 34.000000)
vec2 (2 of 3): (56.000000, 78.000000)
vec2 (3 of 3): (90.000000, 112.000000)

vec3 (1 of 3): (1.000000, 2.000000)
vec3 (2 of 3): (3.000000, 4.000000)
vec3 (3 of 3): (5.000000, 6.000000)

vec4 (1 of 3): (1.000000, 2.000000)
vec4 (2 of 3): (0.000000, 0.000000)
vec4 (3 of 3): (0.000000, 0.000000)
```

Incidentally, I discovered that it's possible to cast the LHS and RHS of the assignment into the pointer type of a struct which holds the amount of data I want to assign:

```
struct bad {double a,b,c,d,e,f};
  struct vec2d *vec5 = calloc(3, sizeof(struct vec2d));
  *((struct bad*) vec5) = *((struct bad*) ((struct vec2d[])
  {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6}
  }));
  print_vec2ds("vec5", 3,  vec5);
```

which "works", but it requires a struct of the precise length to be defined, which isn't really a solution…

Comment: Are the array sizes and values typically hard coded in practice?

Comment: FYI, the RHS is called a "compound literal".

Comment: In C, (almost) anything is possible.

Comment: The only way you'll be able copy an array by assignment is by embedding the array in a structure (because that makes the array size explicit in all contexts).

Comment: catlover2, Try `*dest = *src;`.  Convert the address of the source and destination to address of a `struct` containing the array 3 of `struct2d`.

Comment: @Jeff No, they're not. This question is really just about being able to embed a small handmade array into the source code for testing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think that's more or less equivalent to what I mentioned at the end of my post, where I define a new struct with 6 doubles in it, then cast the addresses to it.

Comment: A `struct` with 3 `struct vec2d` makes more sense than a `struct` with 6 `double`.  Why introduce a new 6 `double` one?

Comment: @catlover2 Is there any issue with just declaring a static array outside of a function? Why does it need to be dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way for me to accomplish this purely as an assignment, without using memcpy?

I believe that the size needs to be known at compile-time in order to do a pure assignment. Otherwise `memcpy()` is a fine solution. If you want to make it a bit simpler you could maybe do something like:

```
  struct vec2d vec2[3] =
  {
    {12, 34},
    {56, 78},
    {90, 112}
  };

  struct vec2d *vec3 = malloc(sizeof(vec2));
  memcpy(vec3, vec2, sizeof(vec2));
```